# Joining mesh with mirror modifiers, but i don't want the modifier on all of them

Tags: mesh, mirror-modifier

So i'm making a character model:

I got the lower half of the body, the 2 arms, and a piece of cloth for the torso. The lower half and the arms both have the mirror modifier on.

I would like to join all of them, but without applying the mirror modifier to the piece of cloth.

How can I do that ?

Comment: you can't, you need to apply the modifier, otherwise it will apply to the joined object

Comment: You can't.  Join results in the modifiers being applied to all of what were previously independent meshes because they're all now one mesh. The old individual meshes are now disconnected islands in the new mesh.  You can almost accomplish what you want with parenting though.  will that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your responses but how do i "apply" the mirror modifier ? there is no apply button.

And how do i use parenting ?

Comment: in the modifier, click on the down arrow and there you'll find the Apply button, or select the modifier and Ctrl A

Comment: Ty moonboots it's exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in comments, you can't.  That's okay, because it's not usually necessary to do so.  Models can usually exist just fine as multiple objects.

Every once in a while, you want a single object with some stuff mirrored and some stuff not, and you want or need that to be live.  In that case, rather than limiting the mirror modifier, you can run a full mirror and then use a mask modifier to delete *some* mirrored geometry:

1. For each object that you don't want mirrored, select it, create a vertex group (we'll call it "mirrormask.L"), and assign all vertices to that vertex group.
2. Join all the objects.  Create a vertex group on the new object that mirrors your first vertex group-- so in this case, "mirrormask.R".
3. On your object's mirror modifier, make sure that "vertex groups" are enabled (default) and that merge is disabled.
4. Give your object a mask modifier.  Specify the vertex group of the mask modifier as mirrormask.R, then invert the vertex group with the button to the right of its field on the modifier.

[image]

If you need mirror's "merge" functionality, you can give it a shot.  It might not cause any problems-- it depends on your specific geometry.  An alternative to merge is the weld modifier, which can be used after masking away any unwanted geometry.